# Error at render Handler.php called from controller, error catching and handling exceptions using instanceof and return back

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5, render

i´m newbie to laravel. I'm trying to handle exceptions in laravel at Handler.php, throwing the exception from the controller. I get different errors trying this, from "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\render()" which i solved adding the Request $request at the index method (don´t know if that´s even possible and right to do). Also tried a lot of different ways, my code is commented in some of the important parts, also, im trying to make an error on the code to check if my error handling works, that´s where my headache begins and nothing about the error handling works. I was trying to make a centralized error handling class at Handler.php, so the catch at my method could be easier. I need really some help to figure out my mistakes please. Thanks! :)

I´ve already tried correcting the errors that pop up, such as the render one, the request one and they just keep going or my page stays at blank withouth nothing. Also i had an error that said the redirecting was bad (i think i made an infinite loop of errors redirecting). I have some tries commented on the code also.

Edit: Already solved. made also a CustomException, so I can handle all exceptions i want at Controller and the ones that are not on the controller try-catch, will be handled at the Handler.php. All the code I uploaded is updated, and of course, the 'thow new exception' is on purpose to try out the code.

Index method at controller:

```
             public function index(Request $request)
{
    try {

        //custom message if this methods throw an exception
        \Session::put('errorOrigin', " mostrando los clientes");

    throw new \App\Exceptions\CustomException('customerror');
        //throw exception to make tests

    //...clients query....
        $user_type = Auth::user()->user_type_id;
        if($user_type == 1){//admin user
            return view('admin.clients.index', compact('clients'));
        }
    }catch(\App\Exceptions\CustomException $e){

        report($e);//report custom exception to laravel error log

        $errorOrigin = Illuminate\Http\Request::session()->get('errorOrigin');
        \Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        \Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        \Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        \Session::flash('error', '¡Ha ocurrido un error' . $errorOrigin . "!" 
        .' Si este persiste contacte al administrador del sistema');
        return redirect()->back();//redirecting with error message at                     session

    }

}
```

render method at Handler.php (App/Exceptions)

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{    $errorOrigin = $request->session()->get('errorOrigin');
    //this return is just some trying
    //return parent::render($request, $exception);
    //return dd($exception);
    //return parent::render($request, $exception);

    //just in case the error is thrown but not handled ad a try  catch, this would handle it.
    if($exception instanceof \App\Exceptions\CustomException) {
        Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        Session::flash('error', '¡Ha ocurrido un error ' . $errorOrigin                                         ."!" .' Si este persiste contacte al administrador del sistema');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    if($exception instanceof \ErrorException) {
        Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        Session::flash('error', '¡Ha ocurrido un error ' . $errorOrigin . "!" 
        .' Si este persiste contacte al administrador del sistema');
        return redirect()->back();

    }elseif($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        Session::flash('error', '¡La página a la que ha intentado
        acceder no existe o no es accesible en este momento!');
        return back();

    }elseif($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError) {
        Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        Session::flash('error', '¡Ha ocurrido un error!');
        return back();
    }elseif($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

    }elseif($exception instanceof \UnexpectedValueException) {
        Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        Session::flash('error', '¡Ha ocurrido un error con un valor no válido al ' . $errorOrigin . "!" 
        .' Si este persiste contacte al administrador del sistema');
        return back();

    }elseif($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\QueryException) {
        Session::flash('message_type', 'negative');
        Session::flash('message_icon', 'hide');
        Session::flash('message_header', 'Success');
        Session::flash('error', '¡Ha ocurrido un error en la consulta a la base de datos!'
        .' Si este persiste contacte al administrador del sistema');
        return back();

    }else{/*Original error handling*/
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Custom exception class (empty)

```
 <?php 
   namespace App\Exceptions;

      use Exception;

          class CustomException extends Exception
              {
                 /**
                  */


              }
```

Comment: You are using `render()` method in controller and `render()` is not defined in controller. According to the docs ```All exceptions are handled by the App\Exceptions\Handler class. This class contains two methods: report and render```. As for using `Request $request` in `Index()` method its completely fine. :)

Comment: So if i leave the catch in blank Handler render will be called right? Right now made that, and i made on purpose an ErrorException, but my code using instanceof of /ErrorException at render() is not making the return back(), so probably is not getting into that if statement any idea of what could it be? Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it, i have a lot of hours trying to figure this out.